# Easy way to retrive timestamp from SQL Server db

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a timestamp column (updated) in my Microsoft Sql Server Database and wish to retrieve the value as a DateTime object using SqlConnection and SqlCommand.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

A timestamp field in a SQL Server database is not related to the date and time, but is merely a sequence number.

A timestamp in MySql is on the other hand a datetime-value.

Comment: Could be usefull then with a solution on how to change the MSSQL DB to cope with timestamps like MsSQL

Comment: You define your own DATETIME-field, and remember to update this field whenever you change the content of the row. This is done automatically with MSSQL timestamp field.